# What is the purpose of the isolated subpanel terminal of a solar inverter?

Tags: electrical-engineering, solar-energy, photovoltaics

In a grid-connected (utility-interactive) battery-based PV system, what is the purpose of the 'Isolated Subpanel' terminal of the inverter?

**EDIT**: Found this descriptive image and hence answered the question myelf.

[image]

Comment: A set of connections that are isolated from others for a particular reason. without a wiring diagram we can but guess...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the answer. The isolated subpanel serves a load-center or distribution panel for backup loads (incase of power outage, etc).

Comment: It can also serve as a money-saving feature. At night or low-light conditions without it batteries would quickly discharge the stored power into the utility grid, then you'd need to purchase power off the grid (for a price higher than what you just sold it for) until PV can produce more. With it you run out of your stored battery power for a long time before you need to start paying for grid power.